# android studio rendering timeout

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a problem with Android Studio. Since this morning I can't edit my layouts through the Design interface. It's stuck on "Initializing Rendering Library" and the IDE freezes. All my layouts were working well yesterday and I haven't changed anything since then.

I have tried to invalidate the cache and restart but without any result.

Answer (score 1):

Try that steps :

1.Update Android SDK and Android Developer Tools.

2.If that will not help, reinstall Android Studio using the newest available version (remember to do a backup of your data and projects).

3.If that will not help,  install other IDE for example [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) and import all your projects to it.

Good luck !

Comment: I have tried reinstalling without success. I know that I can use Eclipse but I'd prefer to use Android Studio as I was doing for a while.

Comment: @46enforce Did you update SDK and ADT ? Did you reinstall using **the newest available** version ? I think that steps will not help you, you sholud use other IDE like Eclipse for example

Comment: @Ty221, Just wanted to say cheers, I reinstalled Android Studio and it fixed my problem. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

For me helped such steps:

1. Remove .gradle folder from the project folder, all *.iml files and
   .idea
2. Remove C:\Users\username.AndroidStudioPreview1.2
3. Run Android Studio without importing settings. This will allow to see a dialog where you can open your project from scratch. If you
   import settings then Android Studio will open previously opened
   *.xml files which caused the problem (hanging "Initializing Rendering Library") and the situation will happen again
4. Run Gradle cleanup
5. Sync project
6. Invalidate cache and Restart
7. Build the project from command line. If use Build from AndroidStudio I got  hanging "scanning files to index..."

Answer (score 0):

1. I reinstalled my android studio without success,
2. Then, I downloaded the sdk again, and change my old sdk-path to the new one
3. After I restarted my studio, it works.
4. The most mysterious thing is, I rechange my sdk-path back to my older one, then every thing is ok,I don't know why,but it solved the problem